# open card-reveal content by hover the activator in materializecss

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

I tried to open the card-reveal content by mouseover the activator content several different ways but none of them worked. Here is a working example of my code in the snippet below.

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
        <img class="activator" src="https://s19.postimg.org/rs95dw3b7/beautiful-flower-pictures-and-wallpapers-2.jpg">
      </div>

      <!-- card text content -->
      <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title activator">
      <p>Name of the listing</p>
    </span>
        <p>$10.00</p>
        <div class="card-content">
          <a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light btn right bottom">view item</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--   card reveal content -->
      <div class="card-reveal">
        <span class="card-title">
      <i class="fa fa-times right"></i>
      <div>Name</div> 
    </span>
        <p>this is the data in the card reveal content</p>
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light btn right bottom">view</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can do something like this http://codeply.com/go/SKBlBBLMQW, but the `activator` should be a small element not the entire image otherwise it will constantly re-open the `card-reveal`

Comment: thankyou skilly,  that's great what actually needed is on hover the **card-reveal** content revealed again on removing the mouse the **card-reveal** should again close(mouse out)

Comment: is there an angular way to do this??

Answer (score 9):

I was searching for a way to do this myself, but then came to the conclusion below. This opens an image card from Materialize CSS when you hover over it, then closes when you leave the card. I hope this helps someone and it should answer this question concisely.

```
$(function() {
    $('.card').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).find('> .card-image > img.activator').click();
        }, function() {
            $(this).find('> .card-reveal > .card-title').click();
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: this should be the answer - concise and does the job

Comment: is there an angular way to do this?

Comment: This was literally exactly what I needed! Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use CSS or SASS.

Here's a SASS snippet:

```
.card {
  overflow-y: hidden;

  .card-image {
    & ~ .card-reveal {
      display: block;
      transform: translateY(0%);
      pointer-events: none;
      transition: transform 0.3s;
    }

    &:active,
    &:hover {
      & ~ .card-reveal {
        display: block;
        transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 1px));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This may seem to be more of a hack than a working solution, but it gets the work done! You may need to add the following to your JS:

```
$(".card").mouseenter(function(e){
    if ($(this).find('> .card-reveal').length) {
        if ($(e.target).is($('.card .activator')) || $(e.target).is($('.card .activator i')) ) {
            // Make Reveal animate up
            $(this).find('.card-reveal').css({ display: 'block'}).velocity("stop", false).velocity(
                {translateY: '-100%'}, 
                {
                    duration: 300, 
                    queue: false, 
                    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
                });
        }
    }

    $('.card-reveal').closest('.card').css('overflow', 'hidden');

});

$(".card").mouseleave(function(){
    // Make Reveal animate down and display none
    $(this).find('.card-reveal').velocity(
        {translateY: 0}, 
        {
            duration: 225,
            queue: false,
            easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
            complete: function() {
                $(this).css({ display: 'none'});
            }
        });
});
```

You can refer this [codepen](http://codepen.io/pratikms/pen/xVYgRe?editors=1010) to get a better idea.

Comment: hi pratik here with your code the card-reveal section is just disapearing instead to sliding down as when we click the close button.  Is it possible to slide down the card-reveal section as it slides up on mouseover for the first time over the card reveal section.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes @Kuladeepsony. Thank you for pointing it out. And apologies, as I should have had it handled in the first place itself. I have modified the jQuery and also updated the codepen link with the appropriate answer. You can check it out and let us all know if that is what you were desiring